# Do we need to same PGP version for decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pgp

Requirement:

In our company Location A uses PGP encryption and sending data over internet.
In Location B, we have to decrypt the file.

Question is what do we require in Location B

1. Do we need to use the same PGP license or buy new license for decryption?.
2. Do we require to manage the keys in Location B
3. Do we need to use the same version(SW) for decrypting in Location B?
4. Can we automate decryption using any tools in location B

Please, this is a urgent requirement and i am not used to this product. Can you kindly help please

Comment: 2. No, you could instead manage passphrases and/or _a_ key in location B.

Comment: Thanks, Who will share the keys to location B?

Comment: What keys?  (3_extra_chars)

Comment: I mean the private keys to decrypt it. Do we need to use the same level of PGP licesnce to decrypt the file?.

Comment: Where should i get the private keys?. I beleive that Sender should encrypt the file using Public key and receiver should decrypt it using private key. So who will give/configure this private Key. Please help though its a basic question. Sorry

Comment: I'm just suggesting that location B could only be managing passphrases and/or _a_ key, not (plural) keys.  I don't know what "level of PGP licesnce" you will need "to decrypt the file".  Location B should generate its private key(s) as part of generating its key-pair(s).  The software will configure any such private keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, So in location B we need to use the same PGP software as Loc A to generate the key in pairs (Public+Private). Is it correct?

Comment: I don't know whether or not you "need to use the same ... to generate the key in pairs (Public+Private)."  I would certainly hope that PGP's versions are compatible with each other.

Comment: This appears to be a support question for the vendor of the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard protocol for using asymmetric cryptography is the following:

- Alice generates a public/private key pair
- Alice publishes her public key + additional steps if you need if you need proper authentication of the key
- Bob retrieves Alice's key (and authenticate it when possible)
- Bob crypts the message using Alice's public key
- Bob sends the encrypted message to Alice
- Alice decrypt the message using her private key.

For this to happen you need a piece of software capable of doing RSA (I guess it's RSA you want?) encryption. If they do require a license, you should purchase one (this is a legal issue, not a security one), but PGP has know alternatives like GPG.

You do not need the same version of the software, you just need a software capable of reading the encrypted material and apply the corresponding decryption algorithm (which is public by the way). Some version of the PGP suite introduces algorithm that were not available before, so you need to understand the capabilities of all partners in term of encryption algorithm.

If you want to automate the treatment, you probably want to use any console tool that might be bundled with your encryption suite. For example, gpg is a set of command line interface, so you can script it to do tasks.